# AFNetworking does not appear to be compatible with WatchKit

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods, watchkit

I have an existing iOS app which uses a framework which uses some CocoaPods. I added a WatchKit App target then added the framework to "Embedded Binaries". At this point, everything still compiles and runs. As soon as I import anything from the framework into the WatchKit extension though, I get an error that says

> Could not build module 'FrameworkName'.

When I build, another error comes up inside one of the framework files:

> 'AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h' file not found.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If yes, please post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Versions of AFNetworking prior to v2.6 would not support WatchOS without modification—see the [AFNetworking requirements](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). As v2.6 was released after this question was posted, this seems certain to be the cause of the issues you were experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

`pod init` again so that CocoaPods generates new targets for your `Podfile`.

Add your dependencies to both your main app and to your extension in the `Podfile`.

Comment: I added the targets to the Podfile, and I still get the same error. Any other ideas?